# How do I execute a custom ResourceInitializer

Tags: moryx

I followed the instructions in the [Template repository](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Template/tree/al/resources) to create the Resources database. But now I want to use a custom `ResourceInitializer` to add Resources to the ResourceGraph. (see my code below)

```cs
namespace MyApplication.Resources.MyResource
{
    [ResourceInitializer(nameof(DummyInitializer))]
    public class DummyInitializer : ResourceInitializerBase
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I go into the runtime console and execute `exec ResourceManager initialize`, the initializer is not shown in the list:

[Output in the runtime window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvQS7.png)

How do I get the runtime to show me the `DummyInitializer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Initializers` you see in the console, are the ones configured in the resource managers initializer collection. In the *MaintenanceWeb* you can add an entry for your initializer under: http://localhost/maintenanceweb/#/modules/ResourceManager/configuration?path=ModuleConfig/Initializers
or you can add it the underlying config file.

```
{
  "Initializers": [
    {
      "PluginName": "DummyInitializer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively you can execute it using the resource managers console at: http://localhost/maintenanceweb/#/modules/ResourceManager/console

I hope that helps, let me know if you need further help.